# Time-Series Process, Definition

Tags: statistics

The deifinition of time series is as follows :

[image]
Lets say for example there is a data (lets say monthly sale) collected per month over 20 years. How many random variables are there? Is it 12?

The phrase SEQUENCE OF RANDOM VARIABLES are very confusing. Someone please explain.

Answer (score 0):

A sequence is just an ordered, countable set. As such it can be indexed (i.e. mapped 1 to 1 and onto) by integers. So a "sequence of FOO" is just set of FOO such that you have FOO[1], FOO[2], FOO[3], ... FOO[n] (and potentially going through negative indices too).

A reasonable model for monthly sales is that each month's sales is a random variable, so in 20 years you have 240 variables. However, bear in mind that identifying each month as a separate variable is a modeling choice, not a mathematical choice. Depending on the problem to be solved, maybe each calendar month is a variable, so you have 12 variables and 20 observations for each variable. Or maybe all that matters is the annual sum, so effectively you have 20 variables. Whether or not any of these is appropriate, or none, can only be answered by considering the problem you are trying to solve -- there is no way to prove one modeling choice is better than another.